# plotly js with next js (plot state managemnet,plot reset after state change)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, plotly

I use plotly js with next js I dynamically import the plotly library as below:

```
// @ts-nocheck
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
interface Props {
  data?: any;
  layout?: any;
  config?: any;
  className?: any;
  style?: any;
  useResizeHandler?: boolean;
  onClick?: Function;
}
export default function Plot({
  data,
  layout,
  config,
  className,
  style,
  onClick,
}: Props) {
  const Plot = dynamic(() => import("react-plotly.js"), { ssr: false });
  return (
    <Plot
      data={data}
      layout={layout}
      config={config}
      className={className}
      style={style}
      onClick={onClick}
      // useResizeHandler={useResizeHandler}
    />
  );
}
```

I added a button inside the toolbar to show and hide the legend by adding a state that will modify the layout attribute **showlegend:state**

```
<Plot 
          className={"pl1"}
          data={data1}
          layout={layout1}
          config={{
            modeBarButtonsToRemove: [
              "select2d",
              "lasso2d",
              // "zoomIn2d",
              // "zoomOut2d",
              "autoScale2d",
            ],
            modeBarButtonsToAdd: [
              {
                name: "toggle-legend",
                icon: {
                  path: legendVisibleG1
                    ? image1:image2,
                },
                click: () => {
                  toggleLegendG1();
                  if (legendVisibleG1){

                    layout1["showlegend"]=false
                  }else{
                    layout1["showlegend"]=true
                  }

                },
                title: legendVisibleG1 ? "hide Legend" : "show Legend",
              },]}}
/>
```

**My issue is each time I click on that tool, the plot updates or re-renders and removes any change that I make like zooming to a certain point (the plot reset)**

So what I tried to do, I searched how to save the state of the plot and I saw that plotly implemented that in react like this [react-plotly.js_state-management](https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js#state-management) they created a state that will save user changes, but I don't know how to implement that in next js.

Also I see that react with plotly afford tool that will just implement specific changes to attributes inside the layout as this [plotlyrelayout](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyrelayout) by that I think that specific part of plot will be updated ... but I really don't know how to add that to my next js app, please any help. I hope my question is clear (in short words, I need to make a change on layout without resetting the whole plot).